# Vulkan Buffer WorkGroupID not returning actual value when large number of elements

Tags: buffer, vulkan, shader-storage-buffer

Creating a buffer with `pow(2, 24)` and a `local_size_x = 64` for the layout input qualifier will return `WorkGroupID = 262143` which is all fine due to `pow(2,24) / 64 - 1`, it is zero indexed.

However if we increase the global dimension / no elements / size of the problem to `pow(2, 25)` lets say `WorkGroupID` will return values without a reason, they do not match the math.

Here are some limits that the device got that I think matter:

```
maxStorageBufferRange:          uint32_t = 4294967295
        maxComputeSharedMemorySize:     uint32_t = 32768
        maxComputeWorkGroupCount:       uint32_t[3] = 00000202898A8EC4
            maxComputeWorkGroupCount[0]:    uint32_t = 65535
            maxComputeWorkGroupCount[1]:    uint32_t = 65535
            maxComputeWorkGroupCount[2]:    uint32_t = 65535
        maxComputeWorkGroupInvocations: uint32_t = 1024
        maxComputeWorkGroupSize:        uint32_t[3] = 00000202898A8ED4
            maxComputeWorkGroupSize[0]:     uint32_t = 1024
            maxComputeWorkGroupSize[1]:     uint32_t = 1024
            maxComputeWorkGroupSize[2]:     uint32_t = 1024
```

I do not go overboard with allocating more elements that the device supports.
So after 2 days + 16 hrs I still did not figure out whats going on...

`WorkGroupSize`, `WorkGroupID`, `LocalInvocationID` and `GlobalInvocationID` presents the same problem when I reach a n no. of elements. It is no wonder that `GlobalInvocationID`  presents the same problem due to how it is calculated...

```
#version 450
// Size of the Local Work-group is defined trough input layout qualifier
layout(local_size_x = 64, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;


layout(set = 0, binding = 0) buffer deviceBuffer
{
   uint x[];
};


void main() {
    uint i = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    //uint i = gl_WorkGroupSize.x * gl_WorkGroupID.x * gl_LocalInvocationID.x;


    //x[i] += x[i];

// Total No. of Work Items (threads) in Global Dimension
//x[i] = gl_NumWorkGroups.x;

// Size of Work Dimension specified in Input Layout Qualifier
//x[i] = gl_WorkGroupSize.x;

// Is given by Global Dimension / Work Group Size
x[i] = gl_WorkGroupID.x;

//x[i] = gl_LocalInvocationID.x;

}
```

Comment: "*`WorkGroupID` will return values without a reason*" What precisely does it return? "*if we increase the global dimension / no elements / size of the problem to pow(2, 25)*" And how exactly do you do this? Let's see the dispatch numbers.

Comment: Um, isn't `262143` > the limit `65535`?

Comment: I see that is giving me numbers like 17301503 for WorkGroupID,  which does not make any sense for pow(2,25) for eg.

Comment: Regarding to the limit, not sure how the internals work. If I got a WorkGroupID that is > than the limit in one direction does the hardware helps us with that ? By that I mean does is mapping to two dimension and keeping the relation in software in one dimension ?

Comment: when I do dispatch i use vkCmdDispatch which is recorded inside a command buffer then submited to a queue. Do you think that may have to do with syncronization regarding to the buffer, maybe when I do maping operations to the storage buffer the shader start executing and no enough values are updated in the storage buffer, that may explain why I get those values maybe ?

Comment: vkCmdDispatch have the size in x = pow(2, 25), y  = 1, z = 1

Comment: Well I do not think that there is a sync problem, I even check in debug mode and it seems that the data arrive to device from the host memory, I`ve checked that with some tools from sysInternals ... so probably the problem does not point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> maxComputeWorkGroupCount[0]: uint32_t = 65535
> maxComputeWorkGroupCount[1]: uint32_t = 65535
> maxComputeWorkGroupCount[2]: uint32_t = 65535
> ```
>
> `vkCmdDispatch` have the size in x = pow(2, 25), y = 1, z = 1

Based on the info you provided `groupCountX` = 2<sup>25</sup> = 33554432, but the limit is `maxComputeWorkGroupCount[0]` = 65535 = 2<sup>16</sup>-1.

The Vulkan specification [Valid Usage for vkCmdDispatch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdDispatch-groupCountX-00386) says:

> - `groupCountX` **must** be less than or equal to `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::maxComputeWorkGroupCount[0]`

Violating Valid Usage is undefined behavior. "Undefined behavior" means anything from "everything seemingly working fine" to "your PC colapses into a black hole and destroys this solar system". For all intents and purposes violating Valid Usage is a logical error of the application code.

Comment: Yea, this seems to be one explication for it, I don`t disagree with you on that, and I imagined in my mind that before to post here. Anyway, but, how can explain that if I provide a dispatch size for x a value between pow(2,16), pow(2, 17) .... pow(2, 24) it all works even if the limit is exceeded. Shouldn`t that stop working at the first lets say pow(2,17) ?

Comment: By the way I think you got a typo, WorkGroupID.x for pow(2,25) given local_size_x = 64 should be pow(2, 25)/64 - 1  = 524,287 which is still > than the limit on the device pow(2,16) - 1 = 65535

Comment: @3DSC I covered that; notice my definition of *undefined behavior* in the A. Undefined behavior means **any and every conceivable behavior**, including the case of things working fine despite exceeded limit.

Comment: @3DSC I cannot be sure what you meant by `x`, but I refer to the parameter `groupCountX` of `vkCmdDispatch`. The limit belongs to that parameter, and as you can see in the spec quote there is no division there. AYS the limit is exceeded either way though.

Comment: @3DSC PS: Validation Layers should be able to catch things like this, and they should be always enabled in development phase.

Comment: ok, then I guess if I want to process more work items than pow(2,16) - 1, I guess I need to dispatch work in 2 or 3 dimensions right ? Meaning that I need to divide the size of the problem to the dispatch call, some problems fit well on the hardware, some not, I guess sometimes I need to dispatch more work than the size of the problem, leaving some work on the table to say so. Is that somewhat right ?

Comment: VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump and VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation are enabled however they do not react to this, anyway

Comment: @3DSC Right, seems like it is not implemented yet in the layers. ;; Seems right -- you can always convert 2D/3D back to flat index in the shader.

Comment: I filed a bug against the validation layers: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/2296.