# Vulkan Overlapping Compute Operations with Memory-Access for large datasets

Tags: memory, vulkan, compute-shader

This is somewhat a continuation of [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927866/vulkan-buffer-workgroupid-not-returning-actual-value-when-large-number-of-elemen).

However this time I do not exceed the device limits. So I got a **storage buffer** that is filled with some initial data and I've attached it to a shader that does a read-increment-store in the same storage buffer.

```
void main() {
    data[i] += data[i]
}
```

So by just looking at this can there be any sync issues? I do not see it, each PE is doing its compute with its own data.

What is fun, from the output it looks like a **sin** function in terms of the values, starting at **0** then going **1** then **0**, values that are at the beginning of the buffer are multiplied by themselves few times, the more you go into the buffer you reach the mid where values are multiplied by themselves many times, then we reach the end values are less and less multiplied by themselves. All of the values that are present in the buffer are multiplies of the initial value

Some says that the GPU is hiding memory-latency by overlapping compute operations with memory-accesses. But what kind of overlap is destroying all of my data, though?

Also some note that `vkDispatch(x,y,z)` `x`,`y`,`z` values act somewhat as a multiplier, if I only dispatch on `x` I see less error-prone-output-data, still that shouln't happen, and for large datasets I do reach the limit of the device, so what I do ? → I begin dispatching on `y`, `z` respectively, then when I do that I see more error-prone results.

Comment: Please show how you calculate 'i', and ideally the whole shader and the dispatch command you use to launch it. GPUs (and CPUs, for that matter) do overlap compute and memory access, but always with the constraint that reads, computation, and writes produce the same result as if they didn't overlap (as long as multiple threads aren't accessing the same memory, which they shouldn't be in your code).

Comment: uint i = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x + gl_GlobalInvocationID.y + gl_GlobalInvocationID.z; I even avoid calculate it trough gl_WorkGroupSize, gl_WorkGroupID, gl_LocalInvocationID ...

Comment: The threads with gl_GlobalInvocationID=(1,0,0) and (0,1,0) will access the same location, so that value will get added to itself twice, and because there is no ordering between those threads doing reads and writes, you can end up with either N*2 or N*3 (or, less likely but allowed, some other value).

Comment: So what you suggest ? Doing a return from the shader code ? When ?

Comment: I'm just saying that turning a 2D or 3D invocation ID into a 1D array index is slightly more complicated than just adding the three components together. I gave a simple form of it in my answer below. Generally it takes the form (z * Width*Height) + (y * Width) + x.

Comment: @3DSC: Please put the relevant code in the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have N items, and a maximum dispatch width (x) of MaxX, you want to do something like:

```
int x = N > MaxX ? MaxX : N;
int y = N / MaxX;
if (y * MaxX < N)
    y++; // round up when N isn't an integer multiple of MaxX
vkCmdDispatch(cmdbuf, x, y, 1);
```

And then in your shader:

```
int dispatch_x = gl_WorkGroupSize.x * gl_NumWorkGroups.x;
int i = (gl_GlobalInvocationID.y * dispatch_x) + gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
// number of invocations might be greater than N either because
// N doesn't divide into the workgroup size evenly, or because N
// doesn't divide into dispatch_x evenly (or both).
if (i >= N) return;
data[i] += data[i];
```

Comment: Note this assumes the workgroup size is (1,1,1), which is usually not ideal. You'd need to adjust the calculation of (x,y,z) to deal with rounding to workgroup size (pretty easy if you assume MaxX is a multiple of workgroup width). It's also possible to extend this to three dimensions if MaxX*MaxY is still < N.

Comment: If it assumes workgroup size of `(1,1,1)`, why do you use `gl_GlobalInvocationID` and `gl_WorkGroupSize`? What's with the `if (y * MaxX < N)`? Shouldn't it simply be `int y = (N-1) / MaxX + 1;`?

Comment: I only used that assumption when calculating the `vkCmdDispatch` parameters (to keep it short and clear), not in the shader code. The `if (y * MaxX < N) y++;` is for cases when N doesn't evenly divide by MaxX. For example, MaxX=65536 and N=98304. Your expression does the same thing and is probably what I'd do in practice, but hoped the version I wrote would be clearer / more self-explanatory -- which it obviously wasn't!

Comment: I added a few comments to (hopefully) explain why some of the code is there.